# how to detect/ remove 'UTF-8' code in python (window 10 console )

Tags: python-3.x

saw some answers on this but not really useful

I do some coding with python using blender 2.6
and on occasion I copy text from internet page or from Libre office text document

so there might be some control characters  UTF-8 copied to the text editor for python in blender

problem is I cannot detect where UTF-8 characters are located  in blender text editor or even using outside text editor like notepad 2 or notepad ++

so my question is there a simple way to detect and remove these UNTF-8 characters ?

I mean on window 10 in blender using some python commands or using external text editor!

I need something quick or a simple trick here if possible!

Comment: What is `UNTF-8`? Do you mean `UTF-8`?

Comment: There is no "untf-8". If you mean "utf-8", still blender 2.6 uses Python3 by default and it is able to comply with unicode characters encoded in utf-8, if they are used in a way that makes sense within Python code, of course.  Maybe your problem are simply spacing characters introduced by the html rendering of the code?

Answer (score 0):

sorry it is "utf-8"
in blender at least the error is given as "utf-8"
and very annoying

so when I run a script in bl with some unknown characters it gives an error 
the problem is how can I find where it is and remove it !
The error in blender is given but does not always shows where it is located in the python script!

even if i had to use a text editor that can locate and then help to remove these characters somehow if possible at all